# How can I launch Mozilla Firefox using C++?

Tags: c++, file, execution

Compiled through compiler like Code::Blocks, I have tried the following, bit it does not work:

```
    /*Running Firefox.exe*/

        #include <stdio.h>

    /*using c++*/

        #include <iostream>

        #include <stdlib.h>

        using namespace std;

        int main ()
        {
            int x;
            cout << "Checking if processor is available..." << endl;
/*System used here*/
            if (system(NULL)) puts ("Proceed");

            else exit (1);

            cout<< "Executing Firefox..." << endl;

    /*Having some error here saying not recognized as internal or external command*/

            x = system ("C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe");
/*cout here*/
            cout <<"The value returned was:" << x << endl;


        return 0;
        }
```

Is it because Firefox is not recognized as a system of windows? If so how can I run Firefox, or even Internet Explorer from code?

Comment: Try `system("\"C:/Program...\"");` i.e. quote the path

Comment: What if you try `\\ ` instead of `/`?

Comment: example of a full path? path file directory goes with / but from the example i was referring to which was a calculator.exe it was using \ as its directory path

Comment: Code::Blocks *in not* a compiler; its an IDE.  Most probably you are using it with MinGW/GCC.

Comment: Is it possbile to run firefox in the background without it executing?

Comment: @QWERTY *Is it possbile to run firefox in the background without it executing?* Well you wouldn't be running Firefox then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run cmd.exe (Windows command shell) and enter the string `C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe` at the command line, and you will see the same problem - i.e. the problem is with your command string rather than your C++ code.

The space in the path requires the command string to be quoted:

```
system ("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe\"") ;
```

or

```
system ("\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe\"") ;
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to convert path to DOS format

Launch a command prompt cd into Mozilla Firefox folder

run this: ***`for %I in (.) do echo %~sI`***

Copy the output to `system` command with `\` replaced with `\\` append `firefox.exe` at end

Answer (score 2):

> Is it because Firefox is not recognized as a system of windows?

If you open up `cmd.exe` and type in `C:/Program Files...` it won't work because spaces are used as a delimiter. Quote your path:

```
system("\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe\"");
```

Although if you're targeting Windows you should consider using [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which saves you this trouble.

> If so how can I run Firefox, or even Internet Explorer from code?

If you want to show a web page, use [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)* and let the shell do the work. It will take care of launching Firefox, Internet Explorer, Chrome, or whatever browser the user has configured to view web pages.

*Read the *Remarks* section about initializing COM, first.

Answer (score 0):

Try using windows API [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API

Comment: Does this allows me to run firefox in the background whithout firefox actually launching?